# Node.js Express with PostgresQL, error with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Sorry for the long and vague title.

I am trying to add a new user to my database with an http request. I have no problem creating the tables with my model files but for some reason I can't add a new user.

So here is the error I am getting:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection to database successfull
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

here is my model file `user.js`:

```
export default function createUserModel (sequelize, DataTypes) {
const user = sequelize.define('user',{
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    username:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate (models){
            user.belongsToMany(models.conversation, {through:'UserConversations'});
        }
    }
});

return user;
}
```

The controller (`user_controller.js`):

```
var express = require('express');
var db      = require('sequelize-connect');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

// Create new user
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    try{
        const createdUser = db.models.user.create({
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });

        res.status(200).json(createdUser.dataValues);

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

My curl request:

```
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/ -d '{"email":"test@test.com", "username":"test","password":"123456"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you import your models to sequelize ? . There isn't `user` object in `db.models`

Comment: Sorry I am new to node. What do you mean by importing the models to sequelize? I can see the tables created in my postgres admin?

Comment: @Faellor read the doc [http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#import](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#import)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `return sequelize.define...` instead of `const user = ...`.

The `user` variable is undefined because in this case `return user` will be executed before the variable assignment will be finished.

Read more about asynchronous in node js.